# Multiple alert Javascript

Tags: javascript, alert, getelementbyid

I have a little script that makes a multiple check on two hidden input fields:

```
    function checkfs()
{ 
var rating1 = (document.getElementById("rating").value);
var rating2 = (document.getElementById("rating").value);
var rating3 = (document.getElementById("rating").value);
var check1 = (document.getElementById("countpl").value);
var check2 = (document.getElementById("countpl").value);
var check3 = (document.getElementById("countpl").value);

    if (rating3 == 3 && check3 > 22 || check3 < 19){
        alert("message 1");
        window.location.href = 'myteam.php';}

else if (rating2 == 2 && check2 > 21 || check2 < 18){
        alert("message 2");
        window.location.href = 'myteam.php';}

else if (rating1 == 1 && check1 > 20 || check1 < 17){
        alert("message 3");
        window.location.href = 'myteam.php';}       

else {return true;}    
    }    
    window.onload = checkfs;
```

HTML

```
    <input name="countpl" id="countpl" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row_checkfs['count(f_player.id)']; ?>"/>
<input name="rating" id="rating" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row_checkfs['rating']; ?>"/>
```

I can’t understand how to visualize the correct alert depending on the type of control that has been made. At the moment I always see "alert( "message 1" )" whatever is the problem that has been found. I want the message  1 to appear if rating3 == 3 && check3 > 22 || check3 < 19, the message 2 to appear if rating2 == 2 && check2 > 21 || check2 < 18 etc.
How do I modify the code in order to get this result?

Comment: Your calls to `.getElementById()` ... you're getting the same "id" value 3 times. Why? In any case, the return value from that call is a DOM element, and comparing a DOM element to a number makes no sense.

Comment: The way you're doing this, `rating1`, `rating2`, and `rating3` will all have the same value. Same with `check1`, `check2`, and `check3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
function checkfs()
{ 
var rating = (document.getElementById("rating").value);
var check = (document.getElementById("countpl").value);
alert("rating="+rating+" - Check="+check);
    if (rating == 3 && (check > 22 || check < 19)){
        alert("message 1");
        window.location.href = 'myteam.php';}

else if (rating == 2 && (check > 21 || check < 18)){
        alert("message 2");
        window.location.href = 'myteam.php';}

else if (rating == 1 && (check > 20 || check < 17)){
        alert("message 3");
        window.location.href = 'myteam.php';}       

else {return true;}    
    }
```

I added an alert to see the actual values.

I also used 2 variables instead of 6, and added the parenthesis on the "or" condition.

I think your main reason of failure was the parenthesis on the "or" condition.

You should review the theory about the precedence of the operators.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<script>
function checkfs()
{ 
var rating = (document.getElementById("rating").value);
var check = (document.getElementById("countpl").value);

if (rating == 3 && (check > 22 || check < 19)){
alert("message 1");
window.location.href = 'myteam.php';
}

else if (rating == 2 && (check > 21 || check < 18)){
alert("message 2");
window.location.href = 'myteam.php';
}

else if (rating == 1 && (check > 20 || check < 17)){
alert("message 3");
window.location.href = 'myteam.php';
}

else {return true;}    
}    
window.onload = checkfs;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Also consider using functions for repetitive tasks,

```
function checkfs()
{ 
    var rating = (document.getElementById("rating").value);
    var check = (document.getElementById("countpl").value);
    alert("rating="+rating+" - Check="+check);
    if (rating == 3 && checkThis(check,19,22)){
        alert("message 1");
        window.location.href = 'myteam.php';}

    else if (rating == 2 && checkThis(check,18,21)){
        alert("message 2");
        window.location.href = 'myteam.php';}

    else if (rating == 1 && checkThis(check,17,20)){
        alert("message 3");
        window.location.href = 'myteam.php';}       

    else {return true;}    
} 

function checkThis(tocheck, min, max)
{
   return tocheck<min || tocheck>max;
}
```